# WPF ComboBox selectedValue binding fails

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have an `ObservableCollection<Employee>...`, an `ObservableCollection<Departments>` and `Enployee` is defined as

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int DepId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepId")]
    public virtual Departments Departments { get; set; } 

}
```

and `Department`is defined as

```
public class Departments
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; } 
}
```

In the database I have

[image]

It looks like last ComboBox fails to locate the DepId which belongs to the corresponding Employee！！ Any ideas guys?

```
    <DataGrid  Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10,0,10,10"
               RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
               TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
               CanUserAddRows="False"
               CanUserDeleteRows="False"
               SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
               AutoGenerateColumns="false"
               SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Employees, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Column 1: Employee Id-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Emplyee Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>

            <!--Column 2: First Name-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>

            <!--Column 3: Last Name-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>

            <!--Column 4: Birth Day-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Birth Day" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Birthday}"  BorderThickness="0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--Column 5: Department Id-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Department" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding DepId}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

It looks like last ComboBox fails to locate the DepId which belongs to the corresponding Employee！！ Any ideas guys?

[image]

UPDATE: My viewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ManagerDbContext _context = new ManagerDbContext();
    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }
    private IEnumerable<Departments> _departments;
    public ObservableCollection<Departments> Departments
    {
        get
        {
            return
                new ObservableCollection<Departments>(_context.Departments);
        }
        set
        {
            _departments = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Departments");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Employee> _employee;

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
    {
        get
        {
            return
                new ObservableCollection<Employee>(_context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department));
        }
        set
        {
            _employee = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Employees");
        }
    }
    private Employee _currentSelectedEmployee;
    public Employee CurrentSelectedEmployee
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentSelectedEmployee;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentSelectedEmployee = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentSelectedEmployee");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like spelling error in {Binding Departmentses}

Comment: @Jarek that's not the problem

Comment: Did you correct the Binding spell error ? ItemsSource="{Binding Departmentses}". You can also check the debug output for the binding exceptions.

Comment: @Ugur It doesn't matter. I am sure the names still match.

Comment: Hi, I got your solution (EFThree) and works fine. I just run Configuration code from ViewModel - to be cure that Database has entries. This is the only line I added in Configuration.Seed - context.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now I see the problem. When you use the ItemsSource, then each item of ComboBox gets the binding to Department entity, not to Employee. Does Department entity has a property DepId? Probably not, and that's is the problem. If you need to refer to Employee  you need to do this.

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DepId}
```

---

Employee.Departments what is this? Are you sure it's initialized?

This is what works for me:

```
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Department dept1 = new Department() { Id = 1, Name = "aaa" };
            Department dept2 = new Department() { Id = 2, Name = "bbb" };
            Department dept3 = new Department() { Id = 3, Name = "ccc" };

            ObservableCollection<Department> depts = new ObservableCollection<Department>();
            depts.Add(dept1);
            depts.Add(dept2);
            depts.Add(dept3);

            this.Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " aaaa", DepId = 1, Departments = depts });
            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 2, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " bbbb", DepId = 2, Departments = depts });
            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 3, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " cccc", DepId = 3, Departments = depts });
            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 4, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " dddd", DepId = 2, Departments = depts });

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int DepId { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and this is XAML:

```
<DataGrid  Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10,0,10,10"
       RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
       TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
       CanUserAddRows="False"
       CanUserDeleteRows="False"
       SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="false"
       SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Employees, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Column 1: Employee Id-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Emplyee Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>

        <!--Column 2: First Name-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>

        <!--Column 3: Last Name-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>

        <!--Column 4: Birth Day-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Birth Day" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Birthday}"  BorderThickness="0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--Column 5: Department Id-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Department" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding DepId}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: `Department` entity has no `DepId`. Unfortunately It still shows nothing.

Comment: What fields does Department have?

Comment: Departments is not an Collection that's the problem. Employee should have ObservableCollection<Departments> instead of Departments only.

Comment: I also included my viewModel. Plz have a look !

Comment: Hi, so let's get back to my first answet. Using ItemsSource overrides DataContext. Each item of DataGrid has NO reference to your Departments. I hope this finally will fix your problem: <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=Departments}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding DepId}" />

Comment: @baozi, did u have look the solution. I don't know exactly which point that you are missing ?

Comment: @Ugur I am still working on it. I leave my vs solution at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kid9afrrq90o9ie/AACqNBVLPd77_QMEMBrNu1CFa?dl=0

Comment: @baozi, you can have a look the image that I uploaded. For me it is working

Comment: @Ugur it's not quite the same as i used mvvmlight

Comment: I know,  instead of this code " this.DataContext= this;" ,  you should assign a little bit different.  Like this.DataContext= new MyViewModel();.  Maybe you should consider revise your code.

Comment: Added picture in answer

Comment: Your original answer (and binding) makes no sense. The binding basically says to bind to `DataGrid.DepId`, but DataGrid does not have a property called DepId. Assuming that binding is for the `ComboBox.ItemsSource, you are close though. The RelativeSource part of the binding is correct, and you just need to change the ItemSource binding to something like `Path=DataContext.Departments` so it binds the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to `DataGrid.DataContext.Departments`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31679229/302677) for more details

Comment: Of course does not work because this was the first attempt - there were few :) that's why the question is extended that much, and also the answer kind of obvious ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please have look, it works like that:

```
  <!--Column 5: Department Id-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Department" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="0"  SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding DepId}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image]

and code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
        {
            get { return employees; }
            set { employees = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext= this;

            Department dept1 = new Department() { Id = 1, Name = "aaa" };
            Department dept2 = new Department() { Id = 2, Name = "bbb" };
            Department dept3 = new Department() { Id = 3, Name = "ccc" };


            ObservableCollection<Department> depts = new ObservableCollection<Department>();
            depts.Add(dept1);
            depts.Add(dept2);
            depts.Add(dept3);



            Employees  =new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " aaaa", DepId = 1, Departments = depts });
            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 2, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " bbbb", DepId = 2, Departments = depts });
            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 3, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " cccc", DepId = 3, Departments = depts });
            this.Employees.Add(new Employee() { Id = 4, Birthday = DateTime.Now, FirstName = "aaa", LastName = " dddd", DepId = 2, Departments = depts });


        }

    }
```

Comment: It won't work, because Departments is a member of  MainViewModel. DataGrid.ItemsSource refers to Employees of MainViewModel. therefore DataGrid does not see Departments.

Comment: So this is working project now. I have used his code.

Comment: This works, but it is not ideal because it is creating a new instance of the Departments list for each and every Employee. A better solution is to have one copy of Departments on the same level as the Employees collection, and bind to it using a RelativeSource or ElementName binding, as I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31679229/302677)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set a ComboBox's ItemsSource in a DataGrid would be something like this :

```
// simplified datacontext class
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees;
    public ObservableCollection<Department> Departments;
}
```

```xml
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Emplyee Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Department" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Note the change in the ItemsSource Binding -->
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid1, Path=DataContext.Departments}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding DepId}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

By using an ElementName (or RelativeSource) binding here, we only need to maintain one copy of the entire `Departments` list in our main view model, instead of needing a separate copy of the entire `Departments` list on each and every data item in the DataGrid.

---

But anyways, your actual problem appears to be that you're setting the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to `Employee.Departments`, which is defined as

```
public virtual Departments Departments { get; set; }
```

Since this is not a collection or a list of objects, the ItemsSource does not bind correctly, and therefore the SelectedValue binding does not work as expected.