# How to bind a list property of an object to ComboBoxColumn in wpf datagridview?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridview, combobox

I have an object below. I have a list of these called sourceListofData.

```
public class StringWrapper
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> options{ get; set; }

        public StringWrapper(string val)
        {
            this.Value = val;
            this.Name = val;
            options = new List<string>();
            options.Add("test1");
            options.Add("test2");


        }
    }
```

My goal is to have 1 text column and 1 combobox column. The text column displays Value and the combo box column will have comboboxes where they can link their source to the options property.

Here's how I have the text box in my xaml:

```
   <DataGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="12,161,0,116"
        Name="dgEditConfig" Width="685"
        ItemsSource="{Binding sourceListOfData}"
        AlternatingRowBackground="#CFFA893D" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Table Columns" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
```

My thinking is, I should just have to point to that property of the StringWrapper and it should be able to determine the combobox items like below:

```
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding sourceListOfData}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding options }" />
```

But no matter what path variations I make, I don't even see a combobox show up on the datagridview. I see the textboxcolumn just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By default, I think a DataGridComboBoxColumn displays data as a text, and only changes to a ComboBox if you select the record to edit it. Can try entering Edit Mode of the grid, and see if ComboBox appears? If you want a ComboBox to appear at all times you'll want to use a DataGridTemplateColumn, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31679229/302677)

Answer (score 1):

The DataContext of the columns will be individual items from the ItemsSource of the DataGrid. I'm guessing you will have a single list of objects you want to use as the ItemsSource of the ComboBox, so you will need to use a RelativeSource Binding in order to get the DataContext of an Element higher up the visual tree.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding options, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        SelectedValuePath="ID"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding selectedOption}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```